# Passing xml to url

Tags: php, file-get-contents, json

Im new to xml and i just want to pass an object to url and parse it to array . dont know what to do.

Here's my code:

```
$xml = "<user><name>".$name."</name><balance>".$balance."</balance><address>".$address."</address><mobile>".$mobile."</mobile></user>"; 
   $simple = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
   $simple2 = $simple->asXML();
   $sample = simplexml_load_string($simple2);

$url = $GLOBALS['urlPath'].'webportal_sqlanywhere/xml.php?id='.$(my xml);
      $path_file = file_get_contents($url);
      echo $path_file;
```

Comment: Your title is misleading, what exactly do you need? What does your `file_get_contents()` return?

Comment: I think the reason it might seem incomplete is because your browser is parsing some of the XML as HTML. If you view the source, you can probably see the whole XML in its entirety. I don't get the other part of your question though...

Comment: sorry bout that. All i want to do is to pass the entire xml with its values to the receiver and i think url passing requires only string so  can anybody help. im not that good at programming :(

Comment: Use POAT instead of GET, GET has a limit for the size of data which it can hold, POST can handle larger data sets.

Comment: Hello there sir @DaveChen  . is there a way to pass an xml object to the link mentioned above and ill just parse it to array there

Comment: You'll want to post the contents of `xml.php`, which looks like it's on the same server.

Comment: @Ma'moonAl-Akash .. dunno if I can do that . im passing it via ur

Comment: @DaveChen yes. but its not necessary. I just echoed it to see what xml.php displays. all i wonder was the thing that I can possibly pass my xml to the url. or array perhaps.

Comment: If it is via URL then it uses GET, you need will to use POST to stay on the safe side.

Comment: @Ma'moonAl-Akash can you cite some example sir?  i dont quiet understand. thanks

Comment: Read this link http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Comment: @Ma'moonAl-Akash thanks but I guess it doesnt do what I want with my dilemma. :(